# How to mimic Split Screen feature of MSWord for Android Screen.?

Tags: android

I want my Android Screen (320*480) to be split into two 2 screens each of resolution 320*240 which should mimic the "split Screen" feature of MS Word .How can this be achieved 
Any sample code or any suggestions .
I will be waiting for reply.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of the split screens is fixed anyway why not use a `LinearLayout` which contains 2 sub-layouts?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Upper half" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Lower half" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which will look like

[image]

Comment: This is not what I want. It should be like split screen of MS word, where we will split our screen by clicking "SplitScreen" .Both screens will contain same content. If we make changes in top screen, it should reflect in Bottom Screen. I want this feature to be implemented in Android.

Comment: Any idea regarding how to implement this Split screen feature in android?